# Installed then removed SSL Cert - now getting Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null

Tags: ssl, opencart

A client asked me to install an SSL cert on her site (Krystal.co.uk CPanel hosting, OpenCart 1.5.6.1 website).  I installed cert and edited htaccess file to force https, but encountered various content errors, so removed cert and removed edits to htaccess file.

Today I tried the solution provided in 
https://isenselabs.com/posts/opencart-pages-https

But got errors - so I removed the certificate again, undid my edits, and now I'm getting the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: token in /home/bluebir1/public_html/admin/controller/error/not_found.php on line 16Notice: Undefined index: token in /home/bluebir1/public_html/admin/controller/error/not_found.php on line 22
Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in /home/bluebir1/public_html/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 122

I can access the OpenCart admin panel and login, but unsure what to do next.

This is happening in all browsers, tried reverting my edits but still getting errors.  Tried this solution,

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=199568

but there were no instances of user_token in the file.

Comment: Which version of OC are you use? because only from OC3.0.0. instead `token` using `user_token`

Comment: Ahh sorry, OC 1.5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code in which you are getting the error. 
Also, undefined index means the variable you are trying to use (token) is not defined before. So you could make use isset() function to check whether the variable is set or not.

Comment: The error comes when I try to access the front end of the site, http://bluebirdparties.com/

Comment: The Site Link Alone Won't help me to fix anything. Can you please share the code?